# Intercept back button from soft keyboard

Tags: android

I have the activity with several input fields. When activity started soft keyboard is shown. When back button pressed soft keyboard closes and to close activity I need to press back button one more time.

So the question: is it possible to intercept back button to close soft keyboard and finish activity in one press of back button without creating custom `InputMethodService`?

P.S. I know how to intercept back button in other cases: `onKeyDown()` or `onBackPressed()` but it doesn't work in this case: only second press of back button is intercepted.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, it is completely possible to show and hide the keyboard and intercept the calls to the back button. It is a little extra effort as it has been mentioned there is no direct way to do this in the API. The key is to override `boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent)` within a layout. What we do is create our layout. I chose RelativeLayout since it was the base of my Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.michaelhradek.superapp.utilities.SearchLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.michaelhradek.superapp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
```

Inside our Activity we set up our input fields and call the `setActivity(...)` function.

```
private void initInputField() {
    mInputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchInput);        

    InputMethodManager imm = 
        (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    mInputField.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                performSearch();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    // Let the layout know we are going to be overriding the back button
    SearchLayout.setSearchActivity(this);
}
```

Obviously, the `initInputField()` function sets up the input field. It also enables the enter key to execute the functionality (in my case a search).

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // It's expensive, if running turn it off.
    DataHelper.cancelSearch();
    hideKeyboard();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

So when the `onBackPressed()` is called within our layout we then can do whatever we want like hide the keyboard:

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mInputField.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Anyway, here is my override of the RelativeLayout.

```
package com.michaelhradek.superapp.utilities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

/**
 * The root element in the search bar layout. This is a custom view just to 
 * override the handling of the back button.
 * 
 */
public class SearchLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private static final String TAG = "SearchLayout";

    private static Activity mSearchActivity;;

    public SearchLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SearchLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public static void setSearchActivity(Activity searchActivity) {
        mSearchActivity = searchActivity;
    }

    /**
     * Overrides the handling of the back key to move back to the 
     * previous sources or dismiss the search dialog, instead of 
     * dismissing the input method.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "dispatchKeyEventPreIme(" + event + ")");
        if (mSearchActivity != null && 
                    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            KeyEvent.DispatcherState state = getKeyDispatcherState();
            if (state != null) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                    state.startTracking(event, this);
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && !event.isCanceled() && state.isTracking(event)) {
                    mSearchActivity.onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't take all the credit. If you check the Android [source for the quick SearchDialog box](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/app/SearchDialog.java#SearchDialog.SearchBar) you will see where the idea came from.

Comment: This worked very well, and wasn't too hard to implement (despite looking a little scary).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I just wish I had a way of getting something like that to work with older versions of Android.

Comment: Code can be simplified by just casting `getContext()` to `Activity`. Provided the layout's context is the activity in question of course. But I don't know if it couldn't be.

Comment: static mSearchActivity - that smells wrong by a problem. What if you have two of these in layout? Use non-static variable instead.

Comment: Works like a charm. But, I think it is better to use local static interface and set it implementation from inside activity instead of using static acticty...

Comment: Works for me on Android 6, 7 and 8

Answer (score 86):

**onKeyDown()** and **onBackPressed()** doesn't work for this case. You have to use **onKeyPreIme**.

Initially, you have to create custom edit text that extends EditText. And then you have to implement onKeyPreIme method which controls **KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK**. After this, one back press enough for solve your problem. This solution works for me perfectly.

**CustomEditText.java**

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // User has pressed Back key. So hide the keyboard
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)         

           getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);
            // TODO: Hide your view as you do it in your activity
        }
        return false;
}
```

**In your XML**

```
<com.YOURAPP.CustomEditText
     android:id="@+id/CEditText"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

**In your Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private CustomEditText editText;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      editText = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.CEditText);
   }
}
```

Comment: Love this answer so much. Using this with a fragment as well (within a search bar which doesn't even show up always), and by suggesting to override the editText, this easily encapsulates this behavior to only when its necessary

Comment: Note to everybody: Adding a quick interface to this makes life so much better, and it's fortunately pretty easy to do

Comment: how to call a method in onKeyPreIme() which is in mainActivity.java ?

Comment: You don't need to call onKeyPreIme in activity.  If you use CustomEditText in your activity, method is triggered when you press any button on keyboard.

Comment: in `TODO` area, return true so the call does not propagate to main activity.

Comment: this is way better than the answer above imo

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because it's much more simpler to implement. in fact you just have to copy the class "CustomEditText" (and rename your edittext in XML's) and make what you want in the // TODO area. And just add "return true" in TODO area if you do not want to close your activity. Thanks !

Comment: this was the best answer! been looking for a while...

@Abhigyan you implement a listener in the custom edit text which you then add to the main activity

Comment: just testing in Pixel 4XL device and Nexus emulator, both `onKeyPreIme` and `dispatchKeyEvent` doesn't fired with soft keyboard (only fired with hard keyboard <- type from computer)

Comment: best answer. simple but practical

Answer (score 13):

I found out, that overriding the **dispatchKeyEventPreIme** method of the Layout Class also works well. Just set your main Activity as an attribute and launch a predefined method.

```
public class LinearLayoutGradient extends LinearLayout {
    MainActivity a;

    public void setMainActivity(MainActivity a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
        if (a != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) a
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            if (imm.isActive() && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                a.launchMethod;
            }
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me your xml for this layout? i am trying to check this approach and i have surface view in my custum layout, but it isnt intercepting anything

Comment: Basicly the custom view is the surrounding element in the xml. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view
 class="package.LinearLayoutGradient"...`

Comment: it also works if we simply extend a single view and override it's dispatchKeyEventPreIme(). It is not required to extend the layout itself.

Comment: This approach worked well for me. I extended the layout I was interested in and then passed in a call back interface rather than a reference to the activity.

Answer (score 7):

I had success by overriding **dispatchKeyEvent**:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

It hides the keyboard and finishes the activity.

Comment: this appears to work only on certain devices such as HTC Desire.

Comment: does not work on samsung note 2. The dispatchKeyEvent() is not called when soft keyboard is up.

Comment: Well, I tried this with the Nexus 6 Emulator (Lollipop 5.0) -> worked
and Note 4 (CM12 Lollipop 5.0.2) -> worked not
so, not really the best solution - but anyway.. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Button click is consumed when dismissing the keyboard

Answer (score 4):

How are you showing the soft keyboard?

If you are using `InputMethodManager.showSoftInput()`, you can try passing in a `ResultReceiver` and implementing `onReceiveResult()` to handle `RESULT_HIDDEN`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

Comment: Sounds good, but `showSoftInput()` doesn't show keyboard at my phone and emulator, so I use `toggleSoftInput()`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. onReceiveResult() is called with RESULT_SHOWN, but never later with RESULT_HIDDEN

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but got around it by intercepting the back key press. In my case (HTC Desire, Android 2.2, Application API Level 4) it closes the Keyboard and immediately finishes the Activity. Don't know why this should not work for you too:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

/**
 * Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key
 */
private void onBackPressed() {
    Log.e(TAG, "back pressed");
    finish();
}
```

Comment: this does not work on samsung galaxy note 2. the onkeydown() or onbackpressed() are not triggered when the soft keyboard is visible and the back button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

Use `onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` method and check for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` event. It's very simple without doing any fancy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your BackPressed implementation([Block Back Button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988478/block-back-button-in-android/3988567#3988567)):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

I suggest you to have a look @ [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: I've already tried this, but it still need two presses on back button. As I understand it the first click is intercepted by soft keyboard so `onBackPressed()` doesn't work. And only after the second press program falls into the `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: @Sergey Glotov I tried lots of suggestions for the problem & finally came with a not so good solution where I have to implement own SoftKeyBoard.But I hope android community will soon come out with a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

my version of @mhradek solution:

**Layout**

```
class BazingaLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) :
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

var activity: Activity? = null

override fun dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    activity?.let {
        if (event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            val state = keyDispatcherState
            if (state != null) {
                if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    && event.repeatCount == 0) {
                    state.startTracking(event, this)
                    return true
                } else if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && !event.isCanceled && state.isTracking(event)) {
                    it.onBackPressed()
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event)
}
```

}

**xml file**

```
<com... BazingaLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey">
 </com... BazingaLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (view as BazingaLayout).activity = activity
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my variation of [@kirill-rakhman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615306/kirill-rakhman) solution.

I needed to know when the hardware or gesture back button was pressed while the keyboard was showing so I could react and show a button that had previously been hidden when any of the edit text views had received focus.

1. First declare the call back interface your require

```
interface KeyboardEventListener {
   fun onKeyBoardDismissedIme()
}
```

2. Then create the custom view with the listener for pre ime key events

```
class KeyboardAwareConstraintLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    var listener: KeyboardEventListener? = null

    override fun dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        val imm: InputMethodManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        if (imm.isActive && event?.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            listener?.onKeyBoardDismissedIme()
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event)
    }
}
```

3. Wrap your layout with the custom layout view

```
<com.package_name.KeyboardAwareLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/keyBoardAwareLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

{Your layout children here}    

</com.package_name.KeyboardAwareLayout>
```

4. Next implement the callback interface in your activity or fragment and set on the keyboard aware layout

```
class MyFragment : Fragment, KeyboardEventListener {

    // TODO: Setup some viewbinding to retrieve the view reference

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.keyBoardAwareLayout.listener = this
    }

    override fun onKeyBoardDismissedIme() {
        // TODO: React to keyboard hidden with back button
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this may not work in API 33?