# How to introduce in this AlertDialog a onBackButtonPressed method?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this alertDialog, but when I click on the back button nothing happens:

```
public class LocationQueries {
    Activity context;

    public LocationQueries(Activity context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    protected void promptUserToActivateGps() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage(
                        "GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Enable GPS",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                context.startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                            }
                        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                            promptUserToActivateGps();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

How can I introduce a onBackButtonPressed method ?

Update: I updated the code. When I use it in an activity I do this :

```
   private LocationQueries locationQueries = new LocationQueries(this); 

locationQueries.promptUserToActivateGps();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** This is one way I can think of to achieve what you're trying to do. Basically, pass the `AlertDialog` back to the `Activity` in the `Activity`'s `onBackPressed`-method and do the same thing as my previous answer. Here's the code:

```
public class LocationQueries {
    Activity context;
    AlertDialog alert; // Declare the dialog

    public LocationQueries(Activity context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    protected void promptUserToActivateGps() {
        /* Your method, except change this: */
        alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    // Add a getter for your dialog
    public AlertDialog getAlertDialog() {
        return alert;
    }
}

public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    /* Your other code */
    private LocationQueries locationQueries = new LocationQueries(this);

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog alert = locationQueries.getAlertDialog();
        if(alert != null && alert.isShowing()) {
            alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).performClick();
        }
    }
}
```

**Final edit**: Turns out there's an easier way to do this, as described in `alexc`'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10346421), by using the `AlertDialog`'s `setOnCancelListener`, which is invoked when pressing the back button while the dialog is open, as long as the `AlertDialog.Builder.setCancelable()` is set to `true`.

Comment: I don't want to dismiss it. I want to do the same as the cancel button. Where should I add that ?

Comment: In general when pressing the back-button, or just when pressing the back-button while the dialog is visible?

Comment: Only when the dialog is visible. The dialog is visible until the user will activate the location.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel, see my updated answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your structure, could you update your question with all the relevant code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79911/discussion-between-bogdan-daniel-and-plasma).