# The override method onBackPressed doesn't work when showing popup window

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I want to handle the back press event when showing a popup window in android.
I do like this. 
In the fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    if (backPressStrategy == BACK_PRESS_PLAN_A) {
        if (guideDialog != null) {
            guideDialog.dismiss();
        }
        closeFlashPay(REQ_CLOSE_FLASH_PAY_AND_FINISH);
        return true;
    } else if (backPressStrategy == BACK_PRESS_PLAN_B) {
        if (guideDialog != null) {
            guideDialog.dismiss();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in the Activity, I do like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     PayBaseFragment contentFragment = (PayBaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_CONTENT_FRAGMENT);
     if (contentFragment != null && contentFragment.onBackPressed()) {
         return;
     }
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The problem is, the first time when I pressed back button, the popupwindow just disappeared and the override onBackPressed method was not invoked. Unless I press back button two times.
I show my popup window like this

```
guideDialog.showAtLocation(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I think the dialog is consuming the back press as cancel. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346011/how-to-handle-back-button-with-in-the-dialog

Comment: I saw this link, the problem is that I set the popupwindow forcursable. Should set it false

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you expect to happen. Set onKey listener in the dialog and call  closeFlashPay method there

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the back button key of your dialog with this :

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                                             KeyEvent event) {
                            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                // you can call your onBackPress here

                            } 
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```