# How to enable image_Button to animate and open a pop to confirm "EXIT"?

Tags: java, android, xml

Beginner on androidDevelopment!

I need help in making of **imageButton** to animate on **clickResponse**, and open a pop-up to confirm Exit.

Comment: can you elaborate your requierment please

Comment: While user presses back-Button of an app, the back button needs animation of touch effect and it creates a pop-up conformation menu before closing app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346011/how-to-handle-back-button-with-in-the-dialog see this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement `OnclickListener` to the image button and than open a dialog. You can add animations to a dialog like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5591827/6904440)