# EditText with soft keyboard and "Back" button

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, back

When I'm using "EditText" I have the virtual keyboard.

Pressing first time "Back" button hides the keyboard. Second press invokes "onBackPressed" callback in my activity. OK, but...

I have no idea how to hook the very first press. I need to process input data as soon as the virtual keyboard dismissed.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look into this link. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/28719420/4432143][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28719420/4432143

Comment: Yep, the question is 4 years as outdated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: IS it related to the newest Oreo? I'm no more working with Android for few years and only can recommend to check the solutions from below. As the last resort consult the AOSP sources. Sometimes it can help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can override when the keyboard disappears using this method:

```
  public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && 
       event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           // Do your thing here
           return false;
   }
   return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }
```

Taken from my other answer @ : [Android: Error popup on EditText doesn't move down when keyboard goes away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378259/android-error-popup-on-edittext-doesnt-move-down-when-keyboard-goes-away/6512220#6512220)

Comment: @Blundell why did you use `dispatchKeyEvent` instead of `dispatchKeyEventPreIme`?

Comment: Sorry I can't remember :-) both seem good

Comment: But how do you use it, more explanation pleaseee

Answer (score 0):

**Custom Back Button:-**

```
final RelativeLayout rrBack = (RelativeLayout) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.rr_back);
        rrBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(FEED_DETAIL_TAG_REQUEST);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rrBack.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });
```