# Dismissing a DialogFragment when the soft keyboard is hidden

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a simple `DialogFragment` that contains an `EditText`. When the `DialogFragment` is created the soft keyboard is shown immediately and the `EditText` gains immediate focus by using:

```
    mEditText.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

In fact, what I have is essentially like the example given in this blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

When the back button is pressed, I wish for the `DialogFragment` to be dismissed. What actually happens is that the first back button press causes the soft keyboard to be hidden. A further back press is required to dismiss the `DialogFragment`.

I was quite surprised that there doesn't seem to be a simple API solution for this (such as setting a flag) as I'd have thought it'd be a common requirement.

Having searched on SO the best option seems to be to detect when the soft keyboard has been hidden, and then call `dismiss()` on that event. Such possible solutions for detecting the soft keyboard is hidden are:

[EditText with soft keyboard and "Back" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570974/edittext-with-soft-keyboard-and-back-button)

[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

Before I go ahead and use one of the above solutions, is there any other means I should consider dismiss of the entire `DialogFragment` and soft keyboard with one hit of the back button?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a cancel button instead of exploiting the back one?