# Android soft-input does not disappear when moving back with ActionBar

Tags: android, soft-input-panel

I am using Android SearchWidget on SearchActivity for searches. It automatically gets focus and soft-input keyboard is displayed.

However, when user goes back with ActionBar ([but not with back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570974/edittext-with-soft-keyboard-and-back-button)), the soft-input stays on the screen even though activity has

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustUnspecified"
```

as descripbed on https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

It seems that it only works when going forward, and not coming back.

The problem: there may be many Activities calling SearchActivity and for them making `stateAlwaysHidden` may be not appropriate. (In other words: I don't know behavior of all other Activities.)

UPDATE: Giving code, actually just `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // get the action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (null!=actionBar){
            // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);          
        }
    }        
    ....
}
```

UDATE 2:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: post the code where you go back without using the backbutton

Comment: it is `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: where did you put the action for the setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled?? post your onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: That is just calling `super`. However `onOptionsItemSelected` is great place to hide soft-input, regardless of whatever item is selected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Rod lead and [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    // fix bug when soft-input stays on the screen when navigating away with ActionBar home/back button
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard
    //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN); had no affect
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if(view != null){
        //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);      
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```