# Can an angular directive know when it becomes visible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'd like to make a directive that keeps an element focussed. To do this I just attach a listener to the `focusout` event and call `focus()` when it first. This works great, but if I transition to another state and this directive goes out of scope, I don't want it to keep fighting for the focus.

If I do a

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
```

then I can get notified, but I don't know the current state that was rendering my directive.

Comment: Can you post your directive's code please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just read the `$state.current`.

```
angular.module('constant-focus', [])
.directive('constantFocus', function($rootScope, $state) {
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879759/prevent-keyboard-from-closing/25899264#25899264
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      constantFocus: '=',
    },
    link: function($scope, element) {
      const curState = $state.current;

      const focusFunction = function() {
        if (!$scope.constantFocus) {
          unregister();
          element[0].blur();
        } else {
          element[0].focus();
        }
      };

      /* jslint latedef:false */
      const unregister = () => {
        element[0].removeEventListener('focusout', focusFunction);
      };

      const register = () => {
        element[0].addEventListener('focusout', focusFunction);
      };

      $scope.$watch('constantFocus', enabled => {
        if (enabled) {
          register();
        }
        focusFunction();
      });

      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
        if (fromState === curState) {
          unregister();
        } else if (toState === curState) {
          register();
        }
      });
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: This isn't sufficient. You would also need to listen for `$scope`'s `$destroy` to remove the `$stateChangeStart` listener. Otherwise, if you leave this state and then come back, you'd have two state listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Use the directive's `$scope`'s `$destroy` event to detach the listener. You can do this in either the link or controller functions.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  // Detach focusout listener here
});
```

Comment: This isn't enough since if my view is cached, the `$destroy` event is never fired and the listener will keep fighting for focus.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cached'?

Comment: sorry, I'm using Ionic, which is a layer on top of angular which caches my views in the HTML. See the caching section on http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know Ionic cached views *and* scopes. Thanks for the clarification.