# EditText error is not getting down when keyboard is disable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

In my layout I have 3 EditText with validation condition. When soft keyboard is open error message will display below of EditText. When it goes hide EditText will move down error message still placed top of the layout.

I used **custom edittext** and my layout is in **scroll view** still error message is not get down with edit text.

I have 3 edit text and on button if we click on button it will validate and if everything is correct it will open new activity.

else if in edit text data is not entered error message display.It is process.

When keyboard is show error message display.Keyboard get hide edittext will back to it place but error message still top of layout.

Comment: show your code here for better help

Comment: it contain lot of code if you want i can post set error code.

Comment: no need to put entire app here, just put portion of code which you need to correct

Comment: @YBDevi Please post your codes and the error logs. And I'm confused about what is you except to do?

Comment: when button click it will validate and error message display that code is normal.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving this in your scroll view in xml file

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: I believe you have android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout as parent for your EditText

Comment: no parent is linear layout and layout in scrollview.

Comment: Please try something like
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug which hasn't been fixed yet. However you can work around this problem by subclassing `EditText` class (i.e. custom class) and implementing its `onKeyPreIme` call back method.

```
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // User dismissed the keyboard, so hide and re-show the error message
        revalidateEditText();
        return false;
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

public void revalidateEditText(){
       // Dismiss your original error dialog           
       setError(null);

       // Validate the content and re-show the error message if needed
       validate();
}
```

<sub>Derived from: [Android: Error popup on EditText doesn't move down when keyboard goes away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378259/android-error-popup-on-edittext-doesnt-move-down-when-keyboard-goes-away)</sub>

Note that by implementing `onKeyPreIme`, you can be notified whenever user dismisses the soft keyboard.

Comment: plus one for It's a bug which hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: i am new to android.

Comment: @YBDevi Copy and paste those methods in your subclassed `EditText`.

Comment: k i will try this if it work i will accept your answer.There is no other solution for this problem.

Comment: i don't understand for first edittext error msg work perfect when it for other two box error is placed at top of layout doesn't move down with edittext.

Comment: @YBDevi What do you mean by "...other two box error..."?

Comment: i have 3 edit text first edittext error placed at below of edittext when keyboard close but remaining tow edittext errors place top of layout edit text is move down when keyboard close.

Comment: two box means two edittext sorry if you wrong tying.

Comment: Are your all `EditText`s using your *custom* `EditText`?