# Using onBackPressed() with popup keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

In my app, I have an edit text which, when pressed, sets an `int` value to "1". Obviously, when you press the edit text, a keyboard pops up. The keyboard is dismissed by pressing back, and I have used the following code...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (editingText == 1) {
        editingText = 0;
        setUnit();
    }

    Log.d("Back pressed", "Back was pressed :)");

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

... to change the value back. `setUnit()` then changes the value of a `TextView`H depending on the contents of the `EditText`. However, as I have seen by using the logs, this method is only called when the user backs out of the entire activity, and not when the user backs out of the keyboard.

Is there any way to detect "back" presses when the keyboard is displayed? Or, alternatively, is it possible to change a string's value to match the value of the edit text in real-time? All help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try overriding onKeyEvent in your activity?You can get the back key event in it

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113437/get-back-key-event-on-edittext

Comment: If Francesco verheye's answer is what you mean, Ajit, unfortunately it didn't work. Not sure if this method's deprecated or something, but I put a log in it, and when I clicked back out of the EditText, no log appeared, and the value didn't change. Any other ideas?