# Soft Keyboard hide on backpress

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I need to identify the event of back press which hide the softkeyboard
I have tested by override following methods

1. onKeydown
2. onBackPressed
3. onConfigurationChanged
4. dispatchKeyEvent

But the controller is not reaching there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dispatchKeyEventPreIme in subclassed EditText view:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
    if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == event.getKeyCode()) {
       //do what you need here
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
}
```

Comment: this method is not invoked ,when i cancel the soft keyboard using back button

Comment: i can't find out this method, i get error when i try to override this function

Comment: Hm, where do you override it?  This method is in [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchKeyEventPreIme%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) since API level 3. Are you extending EditText and implementing it there?

Answer (score 0):

An update to @Ludevik's answer

Firstly suggest overriding onKeyDown()

Secondly if the key press has been handled then return true not super.onKeyDown()

Updated code (in Kotlin):

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    // if recognise the keyCode then process 
    return if (keyCode == desiredKeyCode) {
        // do what you need to do
        true // key press handled
    } else {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

As for closing the soft key board - My experience is that can prove problematic (leading to unexpected consequences)