# On first back button press, softkeyboard should not go sown

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have one Activity which contain one Edittext, On launching App Edittext come with Soft keyboard, As shown in above figure

[image]

Now on First back press button I need to display a dilog box.Normally that dialog appear on second back press. As shown above. But image should come with first screen. Please help me.

Comment: Without any code this question is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this code in the `onCreate` method, so that when your app launches, `SoftKeboard` is not displayed:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: That's not a problem, My problem is to show a dialog on first back press without hiding softkeyboard, It's my app requirement.

Comment: which type of dialog you have to display?And Keyboard back pressed or From Button?

Comment: Can You please Explain With Code Or screen Shots Wat You Want to Exactly Do?

Comment: I have added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how you can intercept the back button's key event, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard)

After you implement the code to intercept your event, it's a trivial matter to show a dialog on the first click and dispatch the event (let it occur normally) in the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
     //And Show Dialog  
}
```