# How to handle addTextChangedListener on two EditText together?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, actionlistener

Reququirement :

There are two `EditText` one is Username and another is Password.
I am checking on both `EditText` has more than one character than button of Signup should enable.

Can anyone pls suggest me ?

```
etUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int userName = s.length();
                if(userName >=1){
                    btnSignup.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });
        etPswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpswd);
        etPswd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int pswd = s.length();
                if(pswd >=1) {
                    btnsignup.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });
```

---

```
etUsername.setOnKeyListener(this); 
etPswd.setOnKeyListener(this); 
private void trydisableLoginButton() 
{ 
if(etUsername.getText().toString().length() == 0 && etPswd.getText().toString().length() == 0)
{ btnLogin.setEnabled(false); 
} 
} 

@Override public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{ 
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
{
    trydisableLoginButton(); 
} 
   return false;
 }
```

Req. I am trying to disable the button on Back press of softKeyboard
above code not working!

Comment: Add addTextChangedListener for both and check for condition if EditText1 is blank or not also check EditText2 blank or not , if both are not blank then enable button

Comment: uname.addTextChangedListener(this);
pswd.addTextChangedListener(this); and check on
 @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int pswd = s.length();
    if(pswd >=1) {
     signup.setEnabled(true);
    }
Requirement : for two editText have the 1 character than only  button should enable.
 I have to add two textwatcher and do this.
Any other way pls suggest me.

Comment: post your current code, for other suggestion, your code will help to look into deep

Comment: I updated my answer replace your onKey code with backpressed i edited

Comment: @Ishrat: I am pressing the back button of softkeyboard  Not the hardware key

Comment: means backspace of keyboard???

Comment: Yes,backspace of keyboard.

Comment: if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) this will work for the back key of soft keyboard.

Comment: You should try http://stackoverflow.com/a/28719420/1881611

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027953/back-key-or-delete-key-of-soft-keyboard-not-working-in-4-4-and-5-0?noredirect=1#comment46297608_29027953 @ Isharat can you look at this ?

Comment: I am writing working code you,,for referred question.Please wait

Comment: post the answer on above link @ishrat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to enable signup button

```
 public void tryEnableSignUpButton(){

    if(etUsername.getText().toString().lenght>=1 && (etPswd .getText().toString().lenght>=1 )){

 btnSignup.setEnabled(true);
}

}
```

Now after each

```
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int userName = s.length();
                if(userName >=1){
                   tryEnableSignUpButton();
                }

            }
```

**@EDIT**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      trydisableLoginButton(); 
      super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

Comment: I am glad to know my sol work for you,Thanks for accepting my answer, upvote will be very appreciated.

Comment: onCreate() { etUsername.addTextChangedListener(this);} At this line I am getting the null poniter exception Did you know this ? 03-12 Error :java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginsample/com.example.loginsample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You must cast etUsername before adding listener,  like etUsername=findViewByID(R.id.et_username);

Comment: etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
 etUsername.addTextChangedListener(this); used this still problem I facing.

Comment: please post full log of exception or update your latest code of class

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
  etUsername.addTextChangedListener(this);
     etPswd.addTextChangedListener(this);
     etUsername.setOnKeyListener(this);
     etPswd.setOnKeyListener(this);
  btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
 }

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 10:16:09.680: E/AndroidRuntime(16108):  at com.example.loginsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)

Comment: you not initilising password filed  add this line also  etPswd= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);

Comment: etUsername.setOnKeyListener(this);
     etPswd.setOnKeyListener(this);
private void trydisableLoginButton()
 {
    if(etUsername.getText().toString().length() == 0 && etPswd.getText().toString().length() == 0){
        btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
    }
 }


 @Override
 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  
  if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
   trydisableLoginButton();
  }
  return false;
 } I am trying to disable the button

Comment: Friend ! It's too much in comments you should come to chat,,i will be there to help you,,,start chat now,,,also not post code in comment just update your question

Comment: I can not talk i have only 13 reputation. can someone upvote the question ?

Comment: Okay then, Update your answer not post your code in comment it is not understandable