# Back key or Delete key of Soft Keyboard not working in 4.4 and 5.0?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keyevent

I am facing the issue of back key or del key which is not working in 4.4 and 5.0.1 devices ?
When I press the back key of softkeyboard below method is not calling.

```
 Username.setOnKeyListener(controller);
 Password.setOnKeyListener(controller);

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
            getActivity().setDisableLoginButton();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Anyone suggest me what should I do ?
I am disabling the button if there's no input in username & password.
Please, suggest me also suggest me other solutions if you have.

Comment: you running on emulator or mobile ? because some nexus device having this issue. refer this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42904

Comment: I am running on real devices.

Comment: what is the alternative for my requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i found here
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html

> It is not possible to get Soft Keyboard Key Events

So you should use `TextWatcher` for edit text and get available char and deleted char.

```
 yourTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if(yourTextView.getText().toString().length()<=0){
                    //disabled button here
                    //It means your edittext is empty...
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: check length of input as  int input = s.length(); input as <= 0 disbaled the button

Comment: If you want to disable signup button when edittext is blank then i updated my answer look aftertextChange

Comment: kindly take note, if you editText is empty, textwatcher will not be called at all. I think there should be another answer

Answer (score 0):

> Try this, this worked for me ..

```
public class InputConnectionProxyInput extends AppCompatEditText {
private static final String TAG = "InputConnectionProxyInput";

/**
 * Callback to handle the delete key press event.
 */
public interface SoftKeyDeleteCallback {
    void onDeleteKeyPressed(final EditText source);
}

private SoftKeyDeleteCallback mCallback;

public InputConnectionProxyInput(Context context) {
    super(context);

}


public InputConnectionProxyInput(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public InputConnectionProxyInput(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public void setSoftKeyDeleteCallback(SoftKeyDeleteCallback callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
}


@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    /**
     * Doing this to avoid user selection
     */
    setSelection(this.length());
}

@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new ProxyConnectionWrapper(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs), true);
}

/**
 * Creating a proxy class to handle the delete callback, in 4.3 and above we won't get the KeyEvent callback
 */
private class ProxyConnectionWrapper extends InputConnectionWrapper {

    public ProxyConnectionWrapper(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
        super(target, mutable);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if ( event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && mCallback != null)
            mCallback.onDeleteKeyPressed(InputConnectionProxyInput.this);
        LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "key code " + event.getAction());
        return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
    }





}
```

}