# Prevent Soft Keyboard and popupWindow from closing when any Gridview/ListView Item is being clicked in PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I am working on an android application. In an activity, I am showing a popupWindow on clicking on a button in my activity. This PopupWindow is having an EditText Field. When EditText is in focus the soft keyboard opens. When I type in EditText field, a result matching that query shows in ListView in the same PopupWindow.

[image]

Now, when I click on any item of the Listview in the popupWindow, the softkeyboard and popupWindow both get closed. But I do not want them to be closed. How can I prevent it.

Please help, Thanks a lot in advanced :)

Comment: try this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508270/keyboard-and-popup-window-closes-on-backpress/39508741](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508270/keyboard-and-popup-window-closes-on-backpress/39508741)

Comment: Thanks for reply. The above provided link is the question which I've asked yesterday, but this issue is different. Though the previous issue is also not resolved yet. Please help me if you have any idea about this. How can I prevent popupWindow and keyboard both from closing when I click on any item of gridview/Listview android. Please help