# Which event is fired in android when keyboard is open and we press backbutton

Tags: android, onbackpressed

**What I tested:**

In Android when the keyboard is not opened and we press back button. `onBackPressed()` event is fired

**Question**

***SCENARIO-A:*** In Android when the keyboard is opened and we press back button. The keyboard gets closed. `onBackPressed()` is not fired

***note***: *first time `onBackPressed()` is not called here* ... Only if keyboard is not visible `onBackPressed()` is called

*How to Programatically simulate* ***SCENARIO-A***

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard

Comment: check this out. it Solved the same issue, i had [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36259261/5130987](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36259261/5130987)

Answer (score 0):

> on BackKeyPress check whether the Soft keyboard is open by belowed
>   snippet,if open then close it and prevent onBackPressed(),if not call
>   onBackPressed()

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
        activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            ... close soft keyboard from here
        }
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`onBackPressed()` will not get called when keyboard is shown and it gets closed. Don't know exact reason but it is a fact.

However, if you need to capture the back pressed event when keyboard is shown you can listen for the changes in root/parent layout visibility.

Restating @ReubenScratton who gave excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/6272369) to overcome this issue, we have this code:

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > dpToPx(this, 200)) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
            // ... do something here
        }
    }
});
```

and `dpToPx` function:

```
public static float dpToPx(Context context, float valueInDp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, metrics);
}
```