# edittext focus doesn't allow me to do onKeyBack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I've implemented my fragment in this way: every time a user click on back button, it goes this function:

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if(getView() == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                Fragment fragment = new FlightPerformanceFragment();

                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fragment).commit();

                Log.e("resume","resume FlightPerformance");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

this works good if only there aren't editText focused.
I've searched a lot and I try to solve this problem in this way, using `OnKeyListener`:

```
 View.OnKeyListener onKeyListener = new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                //check if the right key was pressed
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                {
                    if(v == tasET)
                        tasET.clearFocus();
                    else if(v == rhoET)
                        rhoET.clearFocus();

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

 tasET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.paisaET);
 tasET.setOnKeyListener(onKeyListener);
```

the problem is that sometimes the method clearFocus() turn back on the previous editText and it not clear the focus at every editText.

So if this method seems a bit complicate to do simple back operation (I couldn't use onBackPressed() because I need to replace other fragments), is there also a simplest way to do it?

Thank you for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard/5811630#5811630

Comment: @peter I've just try it but don't solve problem

Comment: Does your activity have a windowSoftInputMode attribute defined in the `Manifest.xml` file ?

Comment: @blueware :   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"

Comment: This `getView().requestFocus();` might cause the problem as it requests focus for the whole fragment view. Try to remove it

Answer (score 1):

## Create a custome Edittext and perform back click action on soft keyboard

```
public class MyEdittext extends EditText
{
public MybusinessEdittext(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private KeyImeChange keyImeChangeListener;

public void setKeyImeChangeListener(KeyImeChange listener) {
    keyImeChangeListener = listener;
}

public interface KeyImeChange {
    void onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyImeChangeListener != null) {
        keyImeChangeListener.onKeyIme(keyCode, event);
    }
    return false;
}
}


//perform back click action on soft keyboard 
myEdittext.setKeyImeChangeListener(new MybusinessEdittext.KeyImeChange() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == event.getKeyCode()) {
                //do something here
            }
        }`
```