# How to show soft input keyboard permanently on one screen

Tags: android, focus, android-softkeyboard

I have autocomplete edit text i want that show soft input keyboard even on focus or not on autocomplete. I tried so manny things but non of them is working.
Like in Manifest :

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
    ></activity>
```

In Activity :

```
   number = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.ed_number);

    number.requestFocus();

    InputMethodManager imms = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imms.showSoftInput(number, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
 if (!number.hasFocus()) {
        imm.showSoftInput(number, 0);
        number.requestFocus();

    }
```

// on layout click it flickering on click like show/hide

```
linear_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            InputMethodManager immq = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            immq.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you want to do. What does " i want that show soft input keyboard even on focus or not on autocomplete." mean?

Comment: @MehmetKologlu His means he wanna always focus on AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: yeah u right @DharmbirSingh .

Comment: @MehmetKologlu i just want to show soft input keyboard even on outside clicks of autcomplete box.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Your effort are handsome but i don't know why it is not going to set focus on `AutoCompleteTextView`. So please try one more solution might be it can help you.

```
number.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(final View view, boolean hasFocus) 
            {
                view.post(new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        if (!view.hasFocus()) {
                            view.requestFocus();
                            view.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: thnku sir, but i click outside the textbox it soft keyboard is hide again.

Comment: @SumitKumar Can you show me your code? Have you did any action on outer layout to hide keyboard?

Comment: @SumitKumar Great efforts brother and please subscribe my youtube channel for latest updates on android **https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA5HRmlkT7bqbO56EIlT0UQ**

Comment: Done it boss :)