# Android Back Button Changed when key board is open

Tags: android, back-button, soft-keyboard

back-button screen shot

[image]

I want to know which override method it call when this button is clicked.

I searched around but i couldn't find the answer. If any one know please help.

Thanks

Comment: This is normal behavior. It just changes to better show what it'll do on the next click, which is close the keyboard. Why would you want to change this in the first place?

Comment: Vucko brother i want to perform some action if this button is clicked but it didn't call onBackPressed() method that's why i want to know which method should is call...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept back button from soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Sakib, I think the back button action gets captured by the keyboard rather than making it to your app. You can listen for the event indirectly by listening for configuration changes as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/how-to-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android

Comment: If you have a question that's not related to what you posted here please ask it in a new question. You can imagine how things get muddled if people are asking / answering multiple questions in a single post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use OnBackPressedCallback from new androidx.activity 1.0.0-alpha01 library.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#2018-nov-activity