# Android - What is the name of this button?

Tags: android, system-calls

When the soft keyboard is active, the back button is switched to this one

[image]

What is the name of the button? And what is the method that is called after pressing it?

Comment: give the details of which button you are asking.In the image there are lot of buttons.Which you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are referring to the downward-pointing triangle on the left side of the navigation bar.

> What is the name of the button?

BACK.

> And what is the method that is called after pressing it?

In this case, nothing. The input method editor will be closed.

If there is no input method editor open, `onBackPressed()` will be called on the foreground activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same button, it just changes it's shape. Usually it will change it's function from going back to te previous activity to closing the keyboard. 
The method it calls usually is `onBackPressed()` but in this case the keyboard will consume it's call, it will go to the `onEditorAction()` inside `OnEditorActionListener`, if you want to know how to intercept the action usually consumed by the keyboard you can read more in [Intercept back button from soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score -1):

this one is simply a Hardware back button and on some devices its inside screen as you shown in the screenshot. Its called `Back Button`.

you can override `onBackPressed` method in your `Activity` which will be called when this button is pressed.

```
 @override
 public void onBackPressed() {

      // .... Do your task here       
      super.onBackPressed();
 }
```